# Why is my variable initialised after out of success method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I am trying to develop an authentication android based webservice Rest,I am  using the library Retrofit with async task as an inner class .

I have a variable  called loginstatus returns true if the user exists otherwise false .

the problem is when the compiler out of the **success** method isloginstatus initializes to false.

Here is my activity code :

```
public class CheckLoginActivity extends Activity {

static AlertDialog dialog;
Button b;
UserModel userModel;
TextView statusTV;
EditText userNameET, passWordET;
String editTextUsername;
boolean loginStatus;
String editTextPassword;
String API_URL = "http://192.168.42.60/task_manager/v1/index.php";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
public static final String USERPREFERENCE = "userPreference";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_login);
    final TextInputLayout usernameWrapper = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.usernameWrapper);
    final TextInputLayout passwordWrapper = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passwordWrapper);
    usernameWrapper.setHint("Username");
    passwordWrapper.setHint("Password");
    dialog = new SpotsDialog(this, "Chargement");
    //NameText  control
    userNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    passWordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    //Display Text control
    statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
    //Button to trigger web service invocation
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
    //Button Click Listener
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(USERPREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Check if text controls are not empty
            if (userNameET.getText().length() != 0 && userNameET.getText().toString() != "") {
                if (passWordET.getText().length() != 0 && passWordET.getText().toString() != "") {
                    editTextUsername = userNameET.getText().toString();
                    editTextPassword = passWordET.getText().toString();
                    //        statusTV.setText("");
                    //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();

                    //Call execute
                    task.execute(editTextUsername, editTextPassword);
                }
                //If Password text control is empty
                else {
                         statusTV.setText("Please enter Password");
                }
                //If Username text control is empty
            } else {
                     statusTV.setText("Please enter Username");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and my async task

```
 private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    //Make Progress Bar visible
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .build();
        geolocateApi post = restAdapter.create(geolocateApi.class);

        post.login(editTextUsername, editTextPassword, new Callback<UserModel>() {
            @Override
            public void success(UserModel userModelRecv, Response response) {
                if (userModelRecv != null) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", userModelRecv.getUsername());
                    editor.putString("id", userModelRecv.getUser_id());
                    editor.putString("firstName", userModelRecv.getFirstName());
                    editor.putString("lastName", userModelRecv.getLastName());
                    editor.putString("Role", userModelRecv.getRole());
                    userModel=userModelRecv;
                    editor.commit();
                    loginStatus=true;
                }else  loginStatus=false;
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }

        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    //Once WebService returns response
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Make Progress Bar invisible

        Intent intSucces = new Intent(CheckLoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialog.hide();
        //Error status is false
            if (loginStatus) {
                //Based on Boolean value returned from WebService
                //Navigate to Home Screen
                startActivity(intSucces);
            } else {

                //Set Error message
                statusTV.setText("Login Failed, try again");
            }
        }


    }
```

my interface Retrofit

```
public interface geolocateApi {
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
public boolean login(@Field("username") String username,@Field("password")  String password, Callback<UserModel> response);
```

}

Thanks for your help

Comment: You supply params in task.execute(editTextUsername, editTextPassword); but you don't use them in your asynctask. Maybe your login isn't successful because of that and you come out in the error callback, where your login boolean is still false...?

Comment: yes but it's not probleme of params i remove them and still not working the web service return succes i logged and return true but after out of method success loginstatus return to false .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Retrofit for your login with a callback which basically sends request asynchronously. So by the time your `onPostExecute` is executed retrofit request might still be processing leaving your `loginStatus` to default `false` value. You don't need AsyncTask here as login already is running in background. It should be something like this

```
public class CheckLoginActivity extends Activity {

    static AlertDialog dialog;
    Button b;
    UserModel userModel;
    TextView statusTV;
    EditText userNameET, passWordET;
    String editTextUsername;
    boolean loginStatus;
    String editTextPassword;
    String API_URL = "http://192.168.42.60/task_manager/v1/index.php";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String USERPREFERENCE = "userPreference";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_login);
        final TextInputLayout usernameWrapper = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.usernameWrapper);
        final TextInputLayout passwordWrapper = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.passwordWrapper);
        usernameWrapper.setHint("Username");
        passwordWrapper.setHint("Password");
        dialog = new SpotsDialog(this, "Chargement");
        //NameText  control
        userNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        passWordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        //Display Text control
        statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        //Button to trigger web service invocation
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
        //Button Click Listener
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(USERPREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Check if text controls are not empty
                if (userNameET.getText().length() != 0 && userNameET.getText().toString() != "") {
                    if (passWordET.getText().length() != 0 && passWordET.getText().toString() != "") {
                        editTextUsername = userNameET.getText().toString();
                        editTextPassword = passWordET.getText().toString();
                        //        statusTV.setText("");
                        //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                                .build();
                        geolocateApi post = restAdapter.create(geolocateApi.class);

                        post.login(editTextUsername, editTextPassword, new Callback<UserModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(UserModel userModelRecv, Response response) {
                                dialog.hide();
                                if (userModelRecv != null) {
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                                    editor.putString("username", userModelRecv.getUsername());
                                    editor.putString("id", userModelRecv.getUser_id());
                                    editor.putString("firstName", userModelRecv.getFirstName());
                                    editor.putString("lastName", userModelRecv.getLastName());
                                    editor.putString("Role", userModelRecv.getRole());
                                    userModel = userModelRecv;
                                    editor.commit();
                                    loginStatus = true;


                                    Intent intSucces = new Intent(CheckLoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intSucces);
                                } else {
                                    loginStatus = false;
                                    statusTV.setText("Login Failed, try again");
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                            }

                        });

                    }
                    //If Password text control is empty
                    else {
                        statusTV.setText("Please enter Password");
                    }
                    //If Username text control is empty
                } else {
                    statusTV.setText("Please enter Username");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i think that's right, `onPostExecute()` will be executed with  `loginStatus` still false while retrofit request may still processing

Comment: @Shashank  when i login first time and i give existing user it work but when i type wrong user and then i type existing user it's not work and the retrofit error return null in onfailure ?

Comment: @user3499324 that seems like a total different issue, may be something to do with your server or the way you are making request. retrofit should return with error description, try to make sense out of it (if you can't figure out post a separate question with error code and description)

Comment: @user3499324 how are you handling invalid login on server, reaching to `onfailure()` means at least you are not returning response code 200, maybe 401 ?

Comment: im returning only succes statut code 200 but when i retry send request in onfailure() it work !

Comment: thank you all it work now im just returning 401 when user does'nt exist and it's ok (y)